# RStudio internal PDF viewer

Tags: latex, rstudio

Over RStudio documentation, it mentions an internal PDF viewer (using PDF.js):

https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/200552066-PDF-Preview-and-SyncTeX

I have no such option. Only "Evince" or "No Preview". Using Ubuntu / RStudio 0.98.1102.

How do I activate the internal viewer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In RStudio 0.98, the internal viewer wasn't available on all platforms.

We have, however, recently enabled it on Linux in RStudio 0.99. If you'd like to try it, you can download a preview release here:

http://www.rstudio.com/products/rstudio/download/preview/